# C# - Azure Service Bus - Cancel message processing after a given time

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, cancellation-token

I am building a service bus based application. When my receiver get the message from the service bus, it may take a lot of time to process it, so I would like to await for the processing, but if it takes too much time, the processing should be canceled and the message should be completed.

Here it is the code of my receiver:

```cs
client.OnMessageAsync(async message =>
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("message from api");
                    try
                    {
                        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                        source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                        var task = new Task(() => ProcessServiceBusMessage(message).Wait(), source.Token);

                        await message.CompleteAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        errLog.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                        await message.DeadLetterAsync();
                    }
                }, new OnMessageOptions() { AutoComplete = false, MaxConcurrentCalls = 20, AutoRenewTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) });
```

As you can see I launch my `ProcessServiceBusMessage` function inside a Task, I wait for it and I use a `CancellationToken` to cancel the task after 30 seconds (if the message require more than 30 seconds to complete processing), but it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

EDIT: Specifically the task is not canceled after 30 seconds and it's immediately executed `message.CompleteAsync()`, without waiting for the task

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: The Task is not canceled after 30 seconds, but it's executed immediately the `message.CompleteAsync()` function. I Edit the question to specify this detail

Comment: OK, sorry but it looks like it's the async stuff and I know very little about that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create a task but don't await it, so `CompleteAsync` is called immediately.

This should be a cleaner approach:

```
var task = ProcessServiceBusMessage(message);
await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout));
await message.CompleteAsync();
```

Comment: nit: check if `task` is completed and only then invoke `message.CompleteAsync`. Otherwise it could be the timeout that has lapsed, but the processing is still taking place.

Comment: @SeanFeldman it's true, therefore in case the `WhenAny()` call is completed because of the timeout, how can I stop the `ProcessServiceBusMessage` task?

Comment: @AlessioInnocenzi I'd say `ProcessServiceBusMessage` should then take a `CancellationToken` and us it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to consider using Azure Storage Queue instead?

By default a message is locked for 30sec, so there may be a conflict. Service Bus may be throwing a Lock expired exception before your 30sec cancellation occurs